# Gradle don't import VertX library in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, vert.x

I imported a java project on eclipse where there is build.gradle as follow:

```
plugins {
    // Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
    id 'application'
    id 'java-library'
    id 'eclipse'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'io.vertx:vertx-core:4.2.6'    
    implementation 'io.vertx:vertx-web:4.2.6'
    implementation 'io.vertx:vertx-web-client:4.2.6'
    implementation 'io.vertx:vertx-mqtt:4.2.6'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

    /* for logging */
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:1.7.36'
}
```

But eclipse show an error "The import io cannot be resolved", in the code:

```
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;

/*
 * Data Service as a vertx event-loop 
 */
public class RunService {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        DataService service = new DataService(8080);
        vertx.deployVerticle(service);
    }
}
```

What can i do?

Project structure:

[image]

Comment: Is `vertx-core-4.2.6.jar` shown below the _Project and External Dependencies_ node? If no, right-click the project and choose _Gradle > Refresh Gradle Project_. If yes, do you have a `module-info.java` file? What quick fixes are provided when you go to the line with the import and hit Ctrl+1?

Comment: I don't have Project and External Dependencies node and neither module-info.java.
If i hit ctrl+1 over the line with the import, it tells me to create the class

Comment: Please show a screenshot showing your project structure.

Comment: Posted in the ask

Comment: Which Buildship version do you have? Which Gradle version is used in your project? Better use `id 'application'` instead of `id 'java-library'`.

Comment: Don't know the versions but i tried what you said and nothing...

Comment: What exactly did you try? Please describe it in detail so that it can be reproduced (which buttons did you click, etc.). Why does your question still show `id 'java-library'` and `jcenter()` rather than `id 'application'` and `mavenCentral()`? For the Buildship version see _Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details_, and for the used Gradle version see _Project > Properties: Gradle_.

Comment: Sorry man i'm so hopeless.

Now i try to explain better

Comment: I  downloaded the project from my professor repo and imported in eclipse, but the funniest thing is that a friend of mine did the same and it works!!

After i followed your advices, i changed the build.gradle, i checked the build path, i downloaded again the jdk and the jre, i tried to biuld the project with all of them but nothing, it doesn't work.

I don't know what to do really

Comment: Having both, `id 'application'` and `id 'java-library'` does not make sense and `id 'eclipse'` is not needed. It might caused by the Gradle version, Buildship version and Java version used. So please tell the Buildship version and what you have in _Project > Properties: Gradle_.

Comment: GUYS I DON'T WHY BUT IT WORKS! 

I LOVE YOU <3

Answer (score 0):

JCenter was [deprecated and made read-only](https://blog.gradle.org/jcenter-shutdown) last year. Newer versions from this year, like the ones you're trying to use, will never be on JCenter. You need to replace it with `mavenCentral()`.

Comment: I tried to change it and refresh gradle project, but nothing